# Displaying UserID in datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm having a problem in my User Activity Log. In SQL I put a UserID of the user in the User_Activity_Log but when I run my codes the UserID keep displaying 0 as UserID.

```
string Login = "Login";
Main code = new Main();
string SqlUserID = "SELECT UserID FROM tblUser WHERE Username='" + Convert.ToString(bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text) + "'AND Password'" + Convert.ToString(bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text) + "'";
UserID = code.Converter_string(SqlUserID).ToString();
if (UserID != "")
{
      string SqlLoginName = "SELECT Username FROM tblUser WHERE UserID='" + Convert.ToString(UserID) + "'";
      username = code.Converter_string(SqlLoginName).ToString();
      code.Execute(@"INSERT INTO User_Activity_Log VALUES('" + Convert.ToString(bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text) + "','" + UserID + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + Login + "','" + CIP + "')");

      menu fr = new menu();
      this.Hide();
      fr.Show();
}
```

Heres my code in my converter string

```
 public string Converter_string(string SQL)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = Main.getConnection();
            DataTable consultanttable = new DataTable();
            string StringConsultant;
            SqlDataAdapter Consultantdataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con);
            Consultantdataadapter.Fill(consultanttable);
            foreach(DataRow myrow in consultanttable.Rows)
            {
                StringConsultant = Convert.ToString(myrow[0]);
                return StringConsultant;

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Successfully Login");
        }
        return "0";
    }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I use Winforms in this.

Comment: Can you share the code of `Converter_string` method? Did you debug the code?

Comment: Check the question I put the code of Converter_string.

Comment: Did you debug the code of `Converter_string` ? The foreach loop is executing? Is yes then what is being returned as `StringConsultant`?

Comment: I already debug the code when I debug it the messagebox appear and says Successfully Login

Comment: Unrelated tips: you display a message saying successful when any exception occurs. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: use SQL parameters rather than string concatenation.  `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` are `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block.